# How to join a table that has been joined by another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables (products, product details, loan reports).

I want to display product categories in the loan report table. the product table has one-to-many relation with the product detail table and the product detail table has one-to-many relation with the loan report table.

### Products

```
id
product_categories
```

### Product Details

```
id
product_name
```

### Loan Reports

```
id
date
amount
```

I've displayed it using this code,

```
$data = DB::table('loan_reports')
            ->join('product_details', 'loan_reports.product_details_id', '=', 'product_details.id')
            ->join('products', 'product_details.products_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->get();
```

I want to do it with Eloquent orm but it's always get an error.
Help me please!

the column I want to display is roughly like this

```
| date | product_categories | product_name | amount |
```

The error that I get is the following:

> Trying to get property 'product_name' of non-object

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can you show an error message?

Comment: @timbiegeleisen it says "Trying to get property 'product_name' of non-object"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out "has many through" relationship:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

In ProductDetails model,create relationships.

```
 public function product_info()
 {
   return  $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product','id','products_id');
 }
 public function loan_reports()
 {
   return  $this->hasOne('App\Models\LoanReports','product_details_id','id');
 }
```

Retrieve result using

```
 $product_details = ProductDetails::get(); 
 foreach($product_details as $product_details)
 {
   echo $product_details->product_categories;
   if(isset($product_details->product_info))
   {
     echo $product_details->product_info->product_name;
   }
   if(isset($product_details->loan_reports))
   {
     echo $product_details->loan_reports->date;
     echo $product_details->loan_reports->amount;
   }
 }
```

Comment: i'm sorry, what's the difference between hasOne and belongsTo? because I use belongsTo in my code

Comment: belongsTo is actually reverse of hasOne.But the purpose is same.Simple example is filia_fixi hasOne phone, phone belongsTo filia_fixi.